# What does correlation between two beta coefficients mean?

Tags: correlation, mediation

I am now trying to use PRODCLIN to do the mediation analysis to obtain a confidence interval for binary single mediation analysis. http://ripl.faculty.asu.edu/downloadable-programs/prodclin/ All of the variables I used are binary variables, including IV, mediator and DV. I plugged in the numbers of betas and SEs from the two logit regression models: estimated a and b. [a is the coefficient of IV when regressing the mediator(M) on IV(X). M= constant + aX + residual] [b is the coefficient of the mediator, when r egressing the DV(Y) on both IV(X) and the mediator(M).  Y=constant+ c'X + bM + residual]

The program asked for the correlation rho between a and b. I am not sure what it means by correlation between two coefficients, especially when they were estimated based on logit regression models. I don't know how to obtain the correlation between these two coefficients. I assume that assuming zero is the most conservative way?

Comment: Unless $X$ is orthogonal to the constant vector, the estimated coefficients will be correlated, in which case zero might not be a good choice.  Are you using SAS?  Is your question basically how to extract the covariance matrix for the betas from `PRODCLIN`?

Comment: I am using STATA to obtain the estimated coefficients. And then use PRODCLIN to calculate the confidence interval for the mediation effect (a*b). So, it seem like I should obtain the correlation between a and b in STATA first. It just confused me a lot because all the variables are binary. I don't know what correlation between a and b refers to.

Comment: (+1) I am surprised not to find good explanations available from the first several pages of Google searches.  This question deserves a clear straightforward answer here!